# Cache Results of Extension Method

Tags: c#, caching, optimization, extension-methods

I am interested in a method to cache/store the results of an extension method performed on an arbitrary object.

The intent would be to avoid redundant expensive operations. Take for instance this extension method to turn an integer into an array of integers containing its digits. Please disregard potential optimizations to the method itself... that is not my concern.

```
    public static int[] Digits(this int i)
    {
        List<int> n = new List<int>();

        for (; i > 0; i /= 10)
            n.Add(i % 10);

        n.Reverse();
        return n.ToArray();
    }
```

If the method is called on the same object twice, it must execute twice. My first approach was caching results and checking object equality:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int[] Digits(this int i)
    {
        int[] cache;
        if (ExtensionCache.IsIntegerDigitized(i, out cache))
            return cache;

        List<int> n = new List<int>();

        for (; i > 0; i /= 10)
            n.Add(i % 10);

        n.Reverse();

        ExtensionCache.CacheIntegerDigitization(i, n.ToArray());

        return n.ToArray();
    }
}

static class ExtensionCache
{
    static Dictionary<int, int[]> _digitizedIntegerCache;
    public static Dictionary<int, int[]> DigitizedIntegerCache
    {
        get { return _digitizedIntegerCache ?? (_digitizedIntegerCache = new Dictionary<int, int[]>()); }
    }

    static public bool IsIntegerDigitized(int i, out int[] digits)
    {
        if (DigitizedIntegerCache.ContainsKey(i))
        {
            digits = DigitizedIntegerCache[i];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            digits = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    static public void CacheIntegerDigitization(int i, int[] digits)
    {

        if (DigitizedIntegerCache.ContainsKey(i))
            return; 

        DigitizedIntegerCache.Add(i, digits);
    }
}
```

The biggest problem I foresee here is an ever-growing dictionary of cached results and unchecked memory consumption. I don't want to keep a cache of results on objects that have gone out of scope.

I've used int, a value type, in this example, but I am interested in a solution that would cover reference and value types.

Comment: Why not use C#'s built in caching system? It has a TTL option.

Comment: Also check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization to know the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing your own cache class, you could consider using [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx). It has the ability to limit memory usage or drop cached items based on an absolute or sliding time window.

Comment: Thank you, looks very promising. The Policies look a bit daunting... but that will make it all the more rewarding.